# AWS cronjob for every minute on ec2 free instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Q. I have 1 AWS ec2 free instance where I have deployed my website. and now I want to start 1 cronjob (crontab) that will execute 1 PHP file once per minute. Do I have to purchase anything on AWS server or I can run cron every minutes on free instance too ?

Comment: Side-note: There is no such things as a "free EC2 instance". The AWS Free Usage Tier provides some free usage, such as 750 hours per month of a t2.micro EC2 instance in the first 12 months. You could use 750 instances for 1 hour, or 2 instances for half a month, or any combination. After 750 hours of usage, normal pricing applies.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is it possible to create cron that executes once per minute ?

Comment: Yes. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs have nothing to do with AWS Services. So think of it as a part of your website functionality, what you need to do is to log into your server through ssh and start writing the cronjob you need.

Comment: so I can directly start cron that executes once a minute with crontab -e command, right? there os no limit like cron must be of 30 minutes or something like that?

Comment: There is no time limitation because its more related to the OS than to AWS.  So you are free to set the cron as 1 minute

Comment: * * * * * php /var/www/html/APIs/add_user.php is the code I used in crontab but it's not working as I have created 1 .txt file and every time add_user.php executes it will date-time to .txt file and it's working when I execute this file manually

Comment: try to set the full path for the php binary

Comment: * * * * * /usr/bin/php-7.0 /var/www/html/APIs/shopify_apis/add_user.php like this?

Comment: yes also you can do `whereis php` the result can be used as a full path php binary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188342/discussion-between-sohel-shaikh-and-mostafa-hussein).